# Поменять местами предпоследнее слово первого предложения на первое слово второго предложения

Tags: c

нужно ввести два предложения и поменять местами предпоследнее слово первого предложения на первое слово второго предложения. Сам дошел до того, чтобы просто выводило предпоследнее слово первого предложения и первое второго предложения. Не знаю как сделать так, чтобы эти два слова менялись местами и выводились два предложения, где эти два слова поменяны местами между собой.

Kод:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 50
void main()
{
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    char str1[N];
    char str2[N]; 

    printf("Vvedite stroku:\n");
        char* p = strrchr(str1, ' '); 
        *p = '\0';
        p = strrchr(str1, ' ');
        p++;
        printf("Предпоследнее слово первого предложения: %s", p);
        printf("\n");
    printf("Vvedite stroku2: \n");
        char* h = strchr(str2, ' ');
        *h = '\0';
        printf("Первое слово второго предложения: %s\n", str2);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вычислите их длины. Затем вычислите смещение, на сколько символов надо передвинуть всё, что между словами, где будет его новое место. Сохраните эти слова (в принципе, достаточно хранить только одно слово, но сохранить два — проще). Затем переместите с помощью `memmove` серединку, и запишите слова на новые места. Или выделите отдельно массив, достаточный для двух слов с концом предложения между ними, и запишите в него первое слово второго предложения, потом окончание первого, потом предпоследнее слово, а потом запишите все это в исходную строку...

Comment: Алгоритм понятен, а можете это как-набудь в коде продемонстрировать?

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел внимательнее... Я не обратил внимания, что вы вводите предложения в разные строки. Это обязательное условие? Просто я писал для случая, когда это одна строка с двумя предложениями.

Comment: Кажется, что да, это обязательное условие, если вам не сложно, могли би показать два кода, где предложения в двух строках и в одной.